# cordova upgrade platform from 4.0.0 to 4.1.1 android build failed

Tags: cordova, android-security

After I get an email from google play store, that there are some vulnerability with android version < 4.1.1, I tried to upgrade cordova android platform to 4.1.1.

**What I did**:

1. cordova platform remove android
2. cordova platform add android@4.1.1
3. After cordova build android I get following error:

Execution failed for task ':dexArmv7Debug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>           /Users/USER/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/COMPANY/PATH TO FILE/platforms/android/build/intermediates/dex/armv7/debug --input-list=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/COMPANY/PATH TO FILE/platforms/android/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/armv7/debug/inputList.txt
>     Error Code:
>           2
>     Output:

```
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatHoneycomb;
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
            at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
            at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
            at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

**cordova plugin list**:

com.pylonproducts.wifiwizard 0.2.11 "WifiWizard"

com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"

cordova-plugin-background-mode 0.6.6-dev "BackgroundMode"

cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"

cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.7.2 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"

cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"

cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.2.0 "Geolocation"

cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.3 "Globalization"

cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"

cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 1.4.2 "Screen Orientation"

cordova-plugin-spinner-dialog 1.3.1 "SpinnerDialog"

cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"

cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"

cordova-plugin-transport-security 0.1.2 "App Transport Security"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"

cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.5.2 "Toast"

de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.1 "LocalNotification"

org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"

phonegap-plugin-push 1.7.1 "PushPlugin"

uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.istablet 1.1.0 "Is Tablet"

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure that it is talking about cordova-android version ? Was the store not speaking about `target-sdkVersion` or `min-sdkVersion` ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! This is what I get https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6325474